# Simulate AR(1) with a matrix of returns in R

Tags: r, autoregressive

I downloaded the closing prices of stocks. Then I computed the returns and saved in a matrix.
Now i want to simulate an AR(1) with the value of the returns. How can i do it?

P.S - in R studio

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](
https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.

Comment: You can use `arima.sim()` for this.